# Understanding Spring and "No EntityManager with actual transaction available"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I have a Spring Boot application with Hibernate, with a bunch of DAOs annotated with `@Repository` and Spring's `@Transactional`. Everything works fine. Then I decide to move common methods (persist, find, merge) to an `AbstractDao`. Writing operations (persist, merge) start throwing that `No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'persist' call` exception. I try adding `@Transactional` to `AbstractDao`, and contrary to my expectations, it fixes it.

Why is that so? I thought that since, unlike CGLIB, Spring uses interfaces instead of extending classes, it wouldn't work, and I would need to define an interface to declare instead of my DAOs. But I also guess that I'm mixing concepts of how Spring deals with dependency management and with transactions.

Can somebody provide an explanation of why does it work? Is there a better way of dealing with this problem?

Comment: is `AbstractDao` a class or interface?

Comment: If you are already using Spring then save yourself the trouble and use Spring data http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/.

Comment: @JasonZ An abstract class

Comment: @AlanHay I tried it, but I kept running into problems so I switched to Hibernate.

Comment: @luispz- Can you please give an idea of what kind of issues you faced with Spring Data JPA? We are planning to use Spring Data JPA in a new project, and it would be insightful to know what all problems did you faced in Spring Data JPA.